# How to data-toggle shared tabs via ul links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I have a dashboard Im building, with a left ul nav-stack and a nav-tabs to the right.  I want to have each link on the left open the same nav tabs but with different corresponding content.  So the 'Status' link will show 4 tabs with different Status info, and 'Projects' showing 4 categories therein, etc.  In other words, each link on left should show a new set of tab panes and content, all sharing the same tab structure. Couldnt find a solution, Im sure theres a trick Im missing.

Heres current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 pull-left text-center">
        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
            <li> <a href="/dashboard/"> <h4 style="color: seagreen;"> Dashboard </h4> </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#status" data-target="#statusTabs"> Status </a>  </li>
            <li> <a href="#projects"> Projects </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#settings"> Settings </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#account"> Account </a> </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>                  <!-- Left nav stack  -->


  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 text-center">                <!-- Nav tabs -->

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" id="statusTabs">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#status" aria-controls="status" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Server Status </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#projects" aria-controls="projects" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Project Status </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Status3 </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#account" aria-controls="account" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Status4 </a></li>
    </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content align-center">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="status"> <br> <h3>  Status of project development and production. </h3> <p> <i class="fa fa-adjust" style="color:violet;"> </i> In Development , <i class="fa fa-upload" style="color:blue;"> </i> in production, <i class="fa fa-cog" style="color:orange;"> </i> in maintenance, <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"> </i> offine, <i class="fa fa-bolt" style="color:green;"> </i> live.  </p> </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="projects"> <br> Projects you currently have in development, with quick view information on each. </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="settings"> <br> Settings for projects, preferences, and email notifications.  </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="account"> <br> Account details such as username, email, change password, account creation date, purchase history. </div>
    </div>

  </div>    
</div>
```

And dashboard looks like so:

[dashboard snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp8W2.png)

One other annoyance is when collapsing page for mobile display the nav-tabs crowd out the nav-stacked links, rendering them un clickable, like so:

[tabs crowding when collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L95lm.png)

Thank you much for any help.  EDIT : Think what I could do is some back end logic perhaps, like an if li a class=active then display content within tabs, elif other li active, display such content in tabs.  Not sure how to work this - right now I have a separate set of 4 tabs for each link on the left stacked on top of each other - ugly and convoluted looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scrapped this nasty reinvention of the wheel, for a sidebar with each link rendering a page.